# How do I fill teak

Tags: filler

I have a teak deck which has been damaged and as a result, there are chunks missing.

What do I used to fill in the missing chunks? will the results be indistinguishable from the rest of the teak?

Thanks

Comment: Pictures of this would be helpful so we can see what kind of damage we're dealing with.

Comment: Sorry there's likely no way to fill in missing wood and have it be indistinguishable from the rest of the wood. You can in some cases fill with patches of solid wood but even with this you have to be very lucky to get them to meld seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

If the chunks are small, you can try to fill with some epoxy mixed with sawdust while if the chunks are big or affect a decent portion of a strip of teak, probably the only real solution is to replace the entire strip.

As for the appearance, you can try to choose some strips with the color as similar as possible to the old ones, but probably some differences there will be, if not for the fact that some strips are newer.

A possible solution, though much more complex and labour intensive, is to remove all the strips and then use some new and some old so it look like it was deliberate: for example you can put all the new strips on the side(s) or the center or make some type of pattern.